# How to get selected row data from Vaadin Grid with polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, vaadin

I am trying to get the selected row data form vaadin grid using polymer. But I am not able to get.

Here is the my code:

```
this.mileageGrid = this.$$("#mileageSectionGrid");
         this.mileageGrid.addEventListener('selected-items-changed', function() {
                var selected = this.mileageGrid.selection.selected();
                this.selectedRowData = this.mileageGrid.getSelectedRow();
                this.selectedRowData = this.mileageGrid.selection.getSelectedRow();
                if (selected.length == 1) {
                    detailsOpenIndex = selected[0];
                    this.callback(detailsOpenIndex);
                    //this.fire("change-mileage", this.mileage);
                }
        }.bind(this));
```

I didn't get any idea after searching from google and vaadin grid document also.

Can anybody tell me, how to get selected row data?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines seem to be incorrect, and look more like something from the Vaadin Java framework API:

```
this.selectedRowData = this.mileageGrid.getSelectedRow();
this.selectedRowData = this.mileageGrid.selection.getSelectedRow();
```

I think those are probably causing errors in the browser and any following JavaScript is not working. Check for any errors in your browser’s console.

Otherwise I can’t spot any issues in your code (I’m just not sure if you’ve declared `detailsOpenIndex` and `this.callback` outside the visible code).